# How to create grid of kernel density plots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have some some samples of a high dimensional density that I would like to plot. I like to create a grid of them where their bivariate density is plotted when they cross. For example, in Bayes and Big Data - The Consensus Monte Carlo Algorithm, Scott et al. (2016) has the following plot:

[image]

In this plot, above the diagonal are the distributions on a scale just large enough to fit the plots. In the below diagonal, the bivariate densities are plotted on a common scale.

Does anyone know how I can achieve such a plot?

For instance if I have just generated a 5-dimensional Gaussian distribution using:

```
library(MASS)

data <- MASS::mvrnorm(n=10000, mu=c(1,2,3,4,5), Sigma = diag(5))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is relatively easy using the `facet_matrix()` from the ggforce package. You just have to specify which layer goes on what part of the plot (i.e. `layer.upper = 1` says that the first layer (`geom_density2d()`) should go in the upper triangular part of the matrix. The `geom_autodensity()` makes sure that the KDE touches the bottom part of the plot.

```
library(MASS)
library(ggforce)

data <- MASS::mvrnorm(n=10000, mu=c(1,2,3,4,5), Sigma = diag(5))

df <- as.data.frame(data)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_density2d(aes(x = .panel_x, y = .panel_y)) +
  geom_autodensity() +
  geom_point(aes(x = .panel_x, y = .panel_y)) +
  facet_matrix(vars(V1:V5), layer.upper = 1, layer.diag = 2)
```

[image]

More details about `facet_matrix()` are posted [here](https://ggforce.data-imaginist.com/reference/facet_matrix.html).